# How show a animation on all fragments of a view pager in android?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager, translate-animation

I develop an android application (a game) with a viewpager which contains three fragments.
I have a TranslateAnimation with some ImageViews which show "It's your turn, you can play". Currently my animation is showed (I don't if this word exists in english..?) on only one fragment, and if I change of fragment, the animation is keep going on the same fragment so that hide it.

My question is : how show the animation in front of the three fragments, in order that when I change the fragment the animation is always here ?

My FragmentActivity with my ViewPager :

```
public class Principal extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private List<Fragment> fragments;
private ViewPager pager;

private AnimationMessage animAToiDeJouer;
private AnimationMessage animDevoileTesCartes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.principal);
    DataModel.getInstance().setFragmentActivity(this);

    // Création de la liste de Fragments que fera défiler le PagerAdapter
    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    // Ajout des Fragments dans la liste
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageGaucheFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageMilieuFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,PageDroiteFragment.class.getName()));

    // Création de l'adapter qui s'occupera de l'affichage de la liste de Fragments
    this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    // Affectation de l'adapter au ViewPager
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);// Pour éviter de pb de disparition !!
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);

    ImageView atdj_bloc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.atdj_bloc);
    ImageView atdj_haut = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.atdj_haut);
    ImageView atdj_bas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.atdj_bas);
    ImageView dtc_bloc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dtc_bloc);
    ImageView dtc_haut = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dtc_barre_haut);
    ImageView dtc_bas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dtc_barre_bas);

    animAToiDeJouer = new AnimationMessage(atdj_haut, atdj_bloc, atdj_bas);
    animDevoileTesCartes = new AnimationMessage(dtc_haut, dtc_bloc, dtc_bas);

}
...
```

And the FragmentPagerAdapter :

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragments;

//On fournit à l'adapter la liste des fragments à afficher
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (Fragment) this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

I hope you understand what I would like, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewFlipper to animate the imageviews

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729828/1557305

Comment: Thank you for your response, but PageTransformers are animations between the fragments aren't they ? My animation is actually a TranslateAnimation with ImageViews which says "It's your turn, you can play"

Comment: Ok, but my ImageViews are already animated. The problem is that the animation is showed only on one fragment, so if I change the fragment, the animation is not on the new current fragment (it is hidden on the previous one).